# Can someone trace the source of a text msg without a phone number, only a four digit code instead?

Tags: sms

I am receiving phishing texts from someone claiming to be from Chase Bank. There is no return phone number at the top, only a four digit number instead. The police tell me that this text (which obviously has the date and time) cannot be traced because of it.

I cannot believe, with today's technology, that this is true. Does anybody have an answer?

Comment: The phone company can trace it.

Comment: Why does the police tell me I cannot? Will the phone company trace it for me without a warrant?

Comment: You need to ask them

Comment: Have you reported this to Chase and your phone provider? I would imagine that, at a minimum, Chase, would be eager to address the problem.